# Can someone explain why my form fields are dissappering when they are not being selected?

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

[Image of Form Fields Dissapeering When Not Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh4XF.gif)

Hi all,

I am having trouble understanding why my fields are disappearing when they are not selected. I am rendering this form using Crispy Forms (followed via Youtube Tutorial). This feature was working earlier - however, I am not sure why it suddenly stopped working. I have a few other forms in this application and they are facing the same issue.

[Here is the relevant code that is being used to generate the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltEgG.png)

```
class BookAppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = BooksAppt
    fields = '__all__'
    labels = {
        'hp_username': 'Doctor',
        'appt_date': 'Appointment Date',
        'p_username': 'Patients'
    }
    widgets = {
        'appt_date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
    }

def __init__(self, p_username=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BookAppointmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if p_username:
        self.fields['p_username'].queryset = Patient.objects.filter(
            p_username=p_username).values_list('p_username', flat=True)
```

[Relevant HTML being used to render the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tQ2s.png)

```
<div class="container" style="background-color:#E6E6FA">
    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 mt-5">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="display-5 "> Booking an Appointment for {{ user }}</h1>
            <p class="lead">Please Fill in the Following Form to Register an Appointment</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
            <form class="register" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">

                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.errors }}
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                {{ form.p_username|as_crispy_field}}
                {{ form.hp_username|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.appt_date|as_crispy_field }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I feel as though the issue is something related to the bootstrap template I am using not playing nicely with crispy forms. I don't need a complete answer - just something to nudge me in the right direction. Please let me know if there is any other relevant information you need to help debug.

Thanks,
Shwinster

Comment: have you tried rendering the form in a bare bones html page, since you think the fault is coming from bootstrap not playing well with crispy forms.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion -  tried something similar by messing around with the inspect element and was able to figure out that the text was simply being set to the color white XD.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was seen as a result of the bootstrap template. It was setting the text to white when not in focus. I was able to figure this out using inspect element and trying to see what stylistic properties were being set the form element.